# How to show docusign ID in the document

Tags: docusignapi

I am using embedded sign flow. I am able to show signHereTabs in the document, but  I also want to show docusign id of the owner. I am not able to find any option in the api on how to show account owner's docusign id (name, sign & company) in the document. Is there any specific anchor for that ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get that information on the envelope then the sender (or owner) will need to also be a recipient on the envelope and have those tags added.

Another option would be to add data fields for the signer that are locked and populate it with the senders information.

Comment: But I am using embedded signing flow and we can't have owner sign the document every time we want a user to sign a document.

Comment: What if you add them as a CC (carbon copy) recipient?  That way they would not sign the document but still be a recipient of the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few possible solutions here:

1. Add the sender as a recipient to the envelope (i.e. a Carbon Copy recipient or a Signer).
2. Use envelope custom fields to pass the data you need.

For #1 if the sender is already a recipient you can add corresponding `name`, `company`, `email`, and other tags to the envelope.  If you don't want them to be a signer of the envelope you can probably get away with adding them as a CC recipient (so that they simply get a copy of the doc) and give them the same `routingOrder` as the one signer.

Alternatively, for #2 you can use envelope `customFields` which are traditionally used to pass meta data about the envelope around but you can use to store the sender data instead.  See the DocuSign Dev Center and API Guides for more info.

Comment: I am having a little hard time to understand and get this done. I think part of that is because I am using embedded sign apis using docusign node modules and it doesn't seem well documented.

This is how my signers object looks like:

`recipients.signers = [{
                    'email': customerEmail,
                    'name': customerName,
                    'recipientId': 1,
                    'clientUserId': 101,
                    'tabs': {
                        'signHereTabs': [{...}]
                    }
                }];`